# Spark-shell -i path/to/filename alternative

Tags: scala, apache-spark

We have:

```
spark-shell -i path/to/script.scala
```

to run a scala script, is it possible to add something like this to the spark-defaults.conf file so that it always loads the scala script on start up of the spark-shell and thus does not have to be added to the command line.

I would like to use this to store `import _`, credentials and user defined functions that I use regularly so that I don't have to enter the commands every time I start spark-shell.

Thanks,
Shane

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go to spark directory `/bin`, create file `spark-shell-new.cmd` and paste 
`spark-shell -i path/to/script.scala` then run `spark-shell-new` in cmd like a default `spark-shell`.

Comment: Thanks this is a good alternative, I was hoping for a method to achieve this directly, however, there doesn't seem to be a way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
:load <path_to_script>
```

Write all the required lines of code in that script